# How do I install SQL Server 2016 onto my newly configured virtual machine on Azure?

Tags: azure, virtual-machine

How do I install SQL Server 2016 onto my newly configured virtual machine on Azure?

I want the developer version to practice queries etc. The VM works fine but I can't administer it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get it from the microsoft website

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/download-sql-server-management-studio-ssms

Answer (score 0):

this answer is a bit misleading, why don't you create a vm with SQL already installed? that way you save time + don't break licensing agreement

Comment: If you are referring to Wojtek's answer, shouldn't this be a comment?